# Replacing ListFragment with another within ActionBar - new listfragment replaces other fragments, IllegalStateException when pressing back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-listfragment, fragmenttransaction

Okay, so I have a problem.

I have an activity, which controls an ActionBar. In it's onCreate i populate the actionbar like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...some other things
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    siteSpecificFragmentManager.populateActionBar(this, actionBar);
}
```

The last line refers to my method that populates action bar with tabs depending on what tabs I want to show, which ones I want to hide, etc, etc... An example I'm using looks like this. CategoriesFragment is a ListFragment that has no corresponding layout xml, and OfflineFragment is a simple Fragment with a layout xml.

```
public void populateActionBar(Activity activity, ActionBar bar) {

    Tab tab = bar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_sites).setTabListener(
                    new TabListener<CategoriesFragment>(activity,"tag1",CategoriesFragment.class));
    bar.addTab(tab);

    tab = bar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_offline).setTabListener(
                    new TabListener<OfflineFragment>(activity,"tag2", OfflineFragment.class));
    bar.addTab(tab);

}
```

TabListener looks like this:

```
public class MyFragmentListener<T extends Fragment> implements
    android.app.ActionBar.TabListener {

public MyFragmentListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> tClass) {
    this(activity, tag, tClass, null);
}

public MyFragmentListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> tClass,
        Bundle bundle) {

    this.activity = activity;
    this.tag = tag;
    this.tClass = tClass;
    this.bundle = bundle;

    fragment = activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    if(fragment != null && !fragment.isDetached()){
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = activity.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.detach(fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if(fragment == null){
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(activity, tClass.getName(),bundle);
        ft.add(android.R.id.content,fragment, tag);
    } else{
        ft.attach(fragment);
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if(fragment != null){
        ft.detach(fragment);
    }
}
}
```

Ok, all set, let's try whether it works. When the activity starts, I see two tabs on ActionBar, I can switch between both without any problems. First tab contains the list, second tab contains some other things.

When I select an item from the list, I want to push a new ListFragment, called SubcategoryFragment onto it. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("chosen", category[position]);

    Fragment fragment = new SubcategoryFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(getId(), fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("category_to_subcategory");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

And the problems are ->

1: When I select an item in the first tab, my fragment is replaced by the subcategory fragment. However, the list of the subcategory fragment overlays the content of the second, offline tab, the list drawn over the contents.

2: When I press back after switching from category to subcategory, the subcategory fragment pops, and I'm returned to category list. That's okay.
When I select a category, to make a subcategoryfragment, switch to the second tab, and press back, the list disappears. When I click back to 1st tab, the Category fragment is not visible.

3: When I do the things mentioned above, and instead of pressing back in the second tab, i switch back to first tab, and then press back, I'm greeted with

```
06-15 20:11:12.151: E/AndroidRuntime(18971): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: CategoriesFragment{414d9350 #0 id=0x1020002 fanfictionnet_categories}
```

So, as you can see, something doesn't work as I'd like it to. What am I doing wrong?